# Analytical result of cost function

Tags: analysis, derivatives, modules

I have a convex optimization problem with the following cost function: $$f(w) = \frac{1}{2}\beta\cdot(w-w^*)^2 + \alpha|w|$$

where $\alpha,\beta,w^*\in R$ and $w$ is my variable. I have to derivate with respect to $w$ and set the derivative equal to zero.

$$\nabla_w f = \beta w- \beta w^* + \alpha\cdot sgn(w) = 0$$

Now, can you show that from the equation above it the result is:

$$w = sgn(w^*)\text{max}(|w^*| - \frac{\alpha}{\beta}, 0)$$

Comment: You need to be careful, $f$ is not differentiable at $w=0$ and it is possible that fir a range of $\alpha,\beta$ that the solution is $w=0$. Presumably $\alpha, \beta >0$? If it convex, then the subdifferential might be a better approach.

Comment: yes, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both greater than zero. I know that the function is not differentiable in zero but the book from that i'm reading (Deep Learning, Goodfellow and Bengio) provides this result without going into further details.

Comment: I do not have the book, but it would be incorrect to suggest that $f$ is differentiable at $w=0$. In fact, one use of the $l_1$ regularisation is to 'push' coefficients towards zero (this is a very loose statemen)t, so it is frequently the case that a solution is at a 'corner point' (again a loose statement).

Comment: Note  that it is true that a convex function (defined on an open set) is differentiable ae, but the issue with the regularisation is that the $\min$ is often at a non differentiable point. Working with the left & right derivatives will result in the same conclusions as in the answer below, but subdifferentiable calculus is fairly mainstream in ML now.

Comment: I suspect the book gets a lot of press from Musk's comment https://medium.com/@ricomeinl/the-top-10-books-on-ai-recommended-by-elon-musk-and-bill-gates-b57fdc9cac0. I suspect the marketing is better than the mathematics.

Comment: in the book the subdifferential is not mentioned. Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: Perhaps they mentioned the subgradient? If not, and you are concerned about the mathematics, I would suggest looking for a different text. (I have not read the book, but convex analysis is pretty much mainstream in such contexts now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that $\alpha, \beta >0$. Then $f$ is convex, in fact strictly convex and $f(w) \to \infty $ as $|w| \to \infty$ hence it has a unique minimiser.

$f$ is not differentiable at $w=0$, so setting the derivative to zero is not appropriate. Since $f$ is convex, we have that $w$ is a minimiser **iff** $0 \in \partial f(w)$, where $\partial f(w)$ is the convex subdifferential.

A quick computation shows
$\partial f(w) = \begin{cases} \{ \beta(w-w^*)-\alpha \}, & w < 0\\
[-\beta w^*-\alpha, -\beta w^*+\alpha ], & w=0 \\
\{ \beta(w-w^*)+\alpha \} , & w > 0
\end{cases}$

Let $w$ be the unique minimiser. There are three distinct cases to consider, (1) $0 \in [-\beta w^*-\alpha, -\beta w^*+\alpha ]$, (2) $0 < -\beta w^*-\alpha$ and (3) $-\beta w^*+\alpha < 0$.

Note that (1) is equivalent to $|w^*| \le {\alpha \over \beta}$, (2) is equivalent to $w^* < -{\alpha \over \beta}$ and (3) is equivalent to ${\alpha \over \beta} < w^*$.

In Case (1), we see that $0 \in \partial f(0)$ hence $w=0$.

In Case (2), we either have $0 = \beta(w-w^*)-\alpha$ (if $w<0$) or $0 = \beta(w-w^*)+\alpha$ (if $w>0$). The latter case gives $0 = \beta(w-w^*)+\alpha > \beta w + 2 \alpha$ and hence $w <0$ which would be a contradiction, hence $w= w^*+{\alpha \over \beta}$.

Case (3) is similar to Case (2) and gives $w= w^*-{\alpha \over \beta}$.

Combining gives
$w = \begin{cases} w^*+{\alpha \over \beta}, & w^* < -{\alpha \over \beta} \\
0, & |w^*| \le {\alpha \over \beta} \\
w^*-{\alpha \over \beta}, & {\alpha \over \beta} < w^*
\end{cases}$,
which is equivalent to the formula in the question.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. There is still one thing that i don't get. When $w=0$ why the subdifferential is $[-\beta w^* -\alpha, -\beta w^* +\alpha]$? Trying to figure it out (since i don't know what a subdifferential is) looks like you computed the derivative with respect to $w=0^-$ and $w=0^+$.

Comment: The subdifferential is a generalisation of the derivative for convex functions (similar approaches work for locally Lipschitz functions). In the case of a real valued convex function on the reals, the subdifferential  is given by $\partial f(w) = [f_-'(w), f_+'(w)]$.